# Amazon Alexa Smart Home Skill - Centimeters for units of measure

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-smart-home-skill

Building a Water Sensor with Amazon Alexa and I noticed `Centimeters` is not available as units of measure. The closest one is `Alexa.Unit.Distance.Inches`.

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/device-apis/alexa-property-schemas.html#units-of-measure

Has anyone else found an alternative for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your observation is correct, currently centimeters is not a supported unit of measure. I have forwarded this to our internal engineering team for future considerations.

Keep an eye on our blog to stay updated with new features: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/blogs/alexa/alexa-skills-kit